# How to read excel cell values using javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, activex

So, I need to be able to read an Excel sheet and access the values of cells. So far I have just created a small demo in an attempt to test code that I have seen elsewhere, but so far I've had no luck. Here's the demo:

```
 function readFile(){ 
                                var excel=new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
                    var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\temp\\mod9.csv");
                    var excel_sheet = excel_file.Worksheets("mod9");
                    var data = excel_sheet.Cells(1,1).Value;
                    alert(data);
                                    return data
                }
```

Really, with this demo I was just trying to see if I could pull a single value, but whenever I try to run this, it stops at the very first line of the function. It says "ActiveXObject is not defined." If you have another suggested way to read the file, then I would be happy to read that as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should not reply on this ActiveX as it only works in IE, plus user do installed Excel

Comment: ActiveXObject is only available on IE. You won't get this code working on other browsers.

Comment: why not save the excel file in the XML format and use XLST?

Answer (score 1):

As the comments to your question say, it's not recommended to use the *ActiveXObject* in javascript since it will only work in *IE*, if you want to have a cross browser solution you'll have to take another approach. More than that, as @SimonWang commented, not only will the user need to open the page with *IE* he will also need to have *Excel* installed on his machine, otherwise it won't work.

You can read the excel file on the server side, parse the data and return it to the javascript side with let's say an ajax request.
I'm not sure how your server side is implemented, but there are solutions for that with almost every language out there. For example with php, you can check out this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the excel spreadsheet so that any user can see it, you can publish it as a webpage using Google Docs.

Instructions are provided here:

http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55244

Let me know if this helps.

*EDIT*

Sorry I think I got confused by your question.

Have you thought about using excel functionality to export the worksheet as CSV or XML and searching the files that way.

File -> Save As -> Excel Workbook, CSV, XML, Web Page (HTML) ....